# A Knockout array of Miscellaneous Objects

Tags: knockout.js

I'm writing a demo of a basic survey application using Knockout. I need to include two types of questions in my survey and the user will be able to add them as they wish. For example, they might want to add a basic question to the survey followed by a multiple choice question. A basic question would consist of a text label (for the question) and a text field for the end-user input. The multiple choice question would consist of one or more rows, each containing a text label and a check-box.

I've written some Knockout to:
- generate a list of basic questions
- generate a list of selection options for the multiple choice question

What I now need to is store both types of questions in an array so I guess the array object needs to be a more generalised version of a survey question - one that could be a basic text question or a multiple choice question, itself an array of selection options.

I have thought of using a single generalised question object that contains all the elements for all types of questions but there's a lot of overhead there as every simple text question will also need to include an array of selection options and if I add additional types of questions it will only get worse.

Can anyone suggest the best (or most concise) way forwards?

Thanks for looking :)

OK, I've added the following as my JavaScript:

```
var SurveyModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.questions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addQuestion = function (item) {
        self.questions.push( item );
    };
    self.addQuestion("{ name: 'basic-question-template' }");
    self.addQuestion("{ name: 'checkbox-question-template' }");
    self.addQuestion("{ name: 'checkbox-question-template' }");
};

window.jQuery(function () {
    var viewModel = new SurveyModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

...and my markup looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="basic-question-template">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter a question:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: txtQuestion" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter a hint:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: txtResponse" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="checkbox-question-template">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter a question:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: txtQuestion" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Please enter a hint:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="cbValue" data-bind="checked: false" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>

<div id="frmSurvey" class="">
    <h2>Questions</h2>
    <div data-bind='template: { name: scriptID, foreach: questions }'> </div>
</div>
</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason the objects in your obserableArray have to be of the same type.

I would recommend something like this:

- Create an script HTML template for each question type's display mode.
- Create a BaseQuestionModel class for properties that all questions have in common, but at the very least has an identifier property and a property to store the display template to invoke.
- You could also have an edit template, for example, so multiple choice questions can be edited differently than free form text questions, etc.
- Create subclasses from your BaseQuestionModel using BaseQuestionModel.apply(this, arguments) for each question type, setting the display-template property explicitly.
- Push instances of these subclasses to your observableArray.
- Use the template binding to display the question appropriately depending on its display-template.

UPDATE:

So ... you're kind of close with your new code, but not quite.

You're just pushing strings to your question array, not actual objects. So you want something like:

```
var CheckboxQuestion = function() {
var self = this;
self.scriptID = ko.observable('checkbox-question-template');
self.txtQuestion = ko.observable();
self.checked = ko.observable();
}

var BasicQuestion = function() {
var self = this;
self.scriptID = ko.observable('basic-question-template');
self.txtQuestion = ko.observable();
self.txtResponse = ko.observable();
}

var SurveyModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.questions = ko.observableArray([]);
self.addQuestion = function (item) {
self.questions.push( item );
};

bq1 = new BasicQuestion();
bq1.txtQuestion('What is your name?');
bq1.txtResponse('Hint goes here');

self.addQuestion( bq1 );

cbq1 = new CheckboxQuestion();
cbq1.txtQuestion('Are you a zombie?');

self.addQuestion(cbq1);

};
```

Now when your view goes through each member of `questions`, it will have a find the `scriptID` value for the template, and then each template will take the item and apply the observable values to the template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I found the template binding documentation based on what you suggested and it looks very much like that's the way forward. Unfortunately, I haven't made much progress as the last time I even looked at any KO was over a year ago.

Based on your reply, I've created a couple of scripts, one for a question with a textbox reply and the other with a checkbox. I guess I need to then create an instance of each and add them to my base questions array and render the latter using something like this:

<div data-bind='template: { name: questionType, foreach: questions }'> </div>

Comment: OK so I've edited my original question to show how I've tried to do it but I'm still missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: A quick change to my markup and that worked great - thanks and have a great weekend! :)

<div data-bind="foreach: questions" >
    <div data-bind="template: scriptID"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the overhead, or perhaps I'm not understanding your question. If you use something like this:

```
function MainViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.questions = ko.observableArray();
}

function QuestionViewModel(type)
{
  var self = this;
  this.type = type;
  this.textQuestion = ko.observable();
  this.options = ko.observableArray();
  this.addOption = function() { self.options.push(new OptionValueViewModel()); }
}

function OptionValueViewModel() 
{
  this.text = ko.observable();
  this.checked = ko.observable(false);
}
```

You can create new QuestionViewModel passing a type string ('text' or 'select', or something meaninful to you) and then based on the type the UI can draw one or other type of question.

If you put an option to a question you never add that array to the other questions, as each one of them is independently in the viewModel.questions array.

If not... I really don't understand the question.